# Mode flipping of Enum var

Tags: swift

What’s the best way to flip between Enum state?

```
enum EVEN_ODD { case Even, Odd }
var __mode_bit = EVEN_ODD.Even;

for _ in 1...5 {
    __mode_bit = (__mode_bit == .Even) ? .Odd : .Even
}
```

Could the `__mode_bit?:` be simplified?

Comment: Why not using a Bool if `EVEN_ODD` is just using two cases?

Comment: @JacobsonTalom because I’m using the EVEN_ODD enum in a switch statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enums can have the ! operator implemented for them.

```
enum Parity { case Even, Odd }
prefix func !(a: Parity) -> Parity {
    return a == .Even ? .Odd : .Even
}
```

Now I can stuff like

```
var parity_mode = Parity.Even
parity_mode = !parity_mode // .Odd
```

Based on @Simon Gladman answer with reference to [Boolean](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=8)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the Apple documentation on Booleans, they give an example of a Boolean typed enum: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=8

Since you can create an enum from raw, you could toggle the value by:

```
let true = MyBool(rawValue: false)
```

Simon

Comment: TY. I believe I have found a good implementation based on your post.

Answer (score 1):

My preference would be to make the enum conform to `_Incrementable` (which, for some reason, is underscored even though it seems like a reasonable non-internal protocol to me), and make it wrap around.

```
enum EvenOdd {
    case Even, Odd
}

extension EvenOdd: _Incrementable {
    func successor() -> EvenOdd {
        return self == .Even ? .Odd : .Even
    }
}

EvenOdd.Odd.successor()  // == .Even
```

This also gives you a pre/post increment operator for free:

```
var bit = EvenOdd.Odd

++bit  // bit now Even
++bit  // bit now Odd
++bit  // bit now Even etc
```